# SQL add multiple percentage to value in calculation

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to calculate new price based on date with sql.
for base price = 1000

| Escalation | Escalation % | New Price |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1/1/2021 | 10% | 1100 |
| 2/1/2021 | 5% | 1155 |
| 3/1/2021 | 2% | 1178.1 |

how can due it without loop or cursor

Comment: `[New Price] = 1000 * (100 + [Escalation %]) / 100`

Answer (score 0):

You would need 2 tables for this.
Price Table (Date, Price)
Escalation Table (Date, Escalation)

Then just join the price table with the escalation base on date.

Query Sample:

```
SELECT 
P.Date
,P.Price as Base_Price
,P.Price * E.Escalation as New_Price
FROM Price P
LEFT JOIN Escalation E ON P.Date = E.Date
```